# Pepper (SoftBank Robotics): Set moveTo speed in Pepper robot via Python (no ROS)

Tags: robotics, pepper, nao-robot, slam

I'm working on Pepper robot by SoftBank Robotics and I'm trying to write a Python script that dynamically manages the Pepper robot speed .
I'm studying [ALMotion](http://doc.aldebaran.com/2-5/naoqi/motion/almotion.html) and [ALNavigation](http://doc.aldebaran.com/2-5/naoqi/motion/alnavigation.html) APIs, but I'm not able to find a solution.

Do you have some ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[ALMotion::move](http://doc.aldebaran.com/2-5/naoqi/motion/control-walk-api.html#almotionproxy-move1) and [ALMotion::moveToward](http://doc.aldebaran.com/2-5/naoqi/motion/control-walk-api.html#almotionproxy-movetoward1) contain velocity/speed as a normalized value from the interval <0; 1> (and <-1; 0> for the opposite direction).

See e.g. the [Come with me](https://gitlab.fi.muni.cz/nlp/dialog_coming) app to see examples how Pepper's hand joint angles are transformed to its movement speed.